# AWS SAM custom domain fails when using !Ref

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

If I'm defining a custom domain as a standalone resource that I'm referencing with `!Ref` my deployment fails. But if I use the same details for a nested object it works. Any idea why?

> Custom Domains only works if both DomainName and CertificateArn are provided.

```
ApiDomain:
  Type: AWS::ApiGateway::DomainName
  Properties:
    DomainName: api.mydomain.com
    CertificateArn: "arn:aws:acm:blah-blah"
    Route53:
      HostedZoneName: "mydomain.com."

MyApi:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
  Properties:
    StageName: Prod
    Cors: "'*'"
    Domain: !Ref ApiDomain
```

But if I nested the domain object - it magically works:

```
MyApi:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
  Properties:
    StageName: Prod
    Cors: "'*'"
    Domain:
      DomainName: api.mydomain.com
      CertificateArn: "arn:aws:acm:blah-blah"
      Route53:
        HostedZoneName: "mydomain.com."
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use your `ApiDomain` this way. The `Domain` property of the `AWS::Serverless::Api` resource requires a `DomainConfiguration` object. `ApiDomain` is a `DomainName`, which is not the same as a `DomainConfiguration` object. Besides `DomainName`, a `DomainConfiguration` also creates base path mappings and Route 53 records.

If you want to define your custom domain as a standalone resource, you will have to define the base path mappings and the Route 53 record as standalone resources as well.